# Reading from two CSV files

Tags: python, csv, iterator

**My code:**

```
import csv

with open("firstfile.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file1:
    one = csv.DictReader(file1)
    with open("secondfile.csv", "r") as file2:
        for line in one:
            print(line)
            for line2 in file2:
                s = line["Owner"]
                if s in line2:
                    print(True)
                    break
            print(s)
```

When I run this code I get

```
{'File Name': 'hofie.exe', 'Owner': 'hello'}
hello
{'File Name': 'feiofejp.zip', 'Owner': 'yo'}
hello
{'File Name': 'fewfew1.exe', 'Owner': 'foooffoo'}
hello
```

when I am expecting:

```
{'File Name': 'hofie.exe', 'Owner': 'hello'}
hello
{'File Name': 'feiofejp.zip', 'Owner': 'yo'}
yo
{'File Name': 'fewfew1.exe', 'Owner': 'foooffoo'}
foooffoo
```

**firstfile.csv:**

```
File Name,Owner
hofie.exe,hello
feiofejp.zip,yo
fewfew1.exe,foooffoo
```

**secondfile.csv:**

```
ihfoiehofiejwifpewhf
```

What is the issue?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This should answer your question, because `for line2 in file2` is exhausted after the first row of `firstfile`: [iterating over file object in Python does not work, but readlines() does but is inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264805/iterating-over-file-object-in-python-does-not-work-but-readlines-does-but-is)

Comment: That is very interesting. I never realized that but thank you very much for your help!
As I was reading the post that you linked here, it said you can do seek to the first line, could you quickly show where I would put that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkrieger1 correctly said you have exhausted the file and you can't read it again. A nice and sleek way to auto return to start is by using a for else loop, where else checks if you reached eof. After that you can `file.seek(0)` at the begining again.

```py
import csv

with open("firstfile.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file1:
    one = csv.DictReader(file1)
    with open("secondfile.csv", "r") as file2:
        for line in one:
            print(line)
            for line2 in file2:
                s = line["Owner"]
                if s in line2:
                    print(True)
                    break
            else:
                file2.seek(0)
            print(s)
```

**prints**:

```
OrderedDict([('File Name', 'hofie.exe'), ('Owner', 'hello')])
hello
OrderedDict([('File Name', 'feiofejp.zip'), ('Owner', 'yo')])
yo
OrderedDict([('File Name', 'fewfew1.exe'), ('Owner', 'foooffoo')])
foooffoo
```